# Typecasting in C#

Tags: c#

What is type casting, what's the use of it? How does it work?

Comment: [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_conversion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_conversion)

Comment: I can tell you know how to formulate your questions right, homie!

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Casting is usually a matter of telling the compiler that although it only knows that a value is of some general type, you know it's *actually* of a more specific type. For example:

```
object x = "hello";

...

// I know that x really refers to a string
string y = (string) x;
```

There are various conversion operators. The `(typename) expression` form can do three different things:

- An unboxing conversion (e.g. from a boxed integer to `int`)
- A user-defined conversion (e.g. casting `XAttribute` to `string`)
- A reference conversion within a type hierarchy (e.g. casting `object` to `string`)

All of these may fail at execution time, in which case an exception will be thrown.

The `as` operator, on the other hand, never throws an exception - instead, the result of the conversion is `null` if it fails:

```
object x = new object();
string y = x as string; // Now y is null because x isn't a string
```

It can be used for unboxing to a nullable value type:

```
object x = 10; // Boxed int
float? y = x as float?; // Now y has a null value because x isn't a boxed float
```

There are also implicit conversions, e.g. from `int` to `long`:

```
int x = 10;
long y = x; // Implicit conversion
```

Does that cover everything you were interested in?

Comment: @jon Skeet gives answer and it doesn't cover everything it has happened ever ?

Comment: Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2690866/what-is-the-purpose-of-a-question-mark-after-a-type-for-example-int-myvariabl) to see what the question mark does after the `float` type.

Answer (score 4):

Casting means creating a reference to an object that is of a different type to the reference you're currently holding. You can do upcasting or downcasting and each has different benefits.

Upcasting:

```
string greeting = "Hi Bob";
object o = greeting;
```

This creates a more general reference (object) from the more specific reference (string). Maybe you've written code that can handle any object, like this:

```
Console.WriteLine("Type of o is " + o.GetType());
```

That code doesn't need to be changed no matter what objects you set o to.

Downcasting:

```
object o = "Hi Bob";
string greeting = (string)o;
```

Here you want a more specific reference. You might know that the object is a string (you can test this e.g.:

```
if (o is string)
{ do something }
```

Now you can treat the reference as a string instead of an object. E.g. a string has a length (but an object doesn't), so you can say:

```
Console.WriteLine("Length of string is " + greeting.length);
```

Which you can't do with an object.

Answer (score 2):

See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx) or [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/CheatSheetCastingNET.aspx):

> Because C# is statically-typed at compile time, after a variable is declared, it cannot be declared again or used to store values of another type unless that type is convertible to the variable's type
>
> ...
>
> However, you might sometimes need to copy a value into a variable or method parameter of another type. For example, you might have an integer variable that you need to pass to a method whose parameter is typed as double. Or you might need to assign a class variable to a variable of an interface type. These kinds of operations are called type conversions. In C#, you can perform the following kinds of conversions

Comment: From the link: "However, if a conversion cannot be made without a risk of losing information, the compiler requires that you perform an explicit conversion, which is called a cast."

Is it saying casting is the same as explicit conversion?

Answer (score 0):

Casting from one data type to another.

For a general reading see [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_conversion).

See also [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you're explicitly casting, you can take advantage of pattern matching. If you have an object:

```
object aObject = "My string value";
```

You can safely cast the object as a string in a single line:

```
if (aObject is string aString)
{
    Console.WriteLine("aString = " + aString)
    // Output: "aString = My string value"
}
```

Using this, along with an inverted if statement, you can safely cast types, and fail out early if need be:

```
public void Conversion(object objA, object objB)
{
    // Fail out early if the objects provided are not the correct type, or are null
    if (!(objA is string str) || !(objB is int num)) { return; }

    // Now, you have `str` and `num` that are safely cast, non-null variables
    // all while maintaining the same scope as your Conversion method
    Console.WriteLine("str.Length is " + str.Length);
    Console.WriteLine("num is " + num);
}
```