# What is the purpose of a question mark after a value type (for example: int? myVariable)?

Tags: c#

Typically the main use of the question mark is for the conditional, `x ? "yes" : "no"`.

But I have seen another use for it but can't find an explanation of this use of the `?` operator, for example.

```
public int? myProperty
{
   get;
   set;
}
```

Comment: There is corresponding question for *reference type* - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69433546/what-does-a-question-mark-after-a-reference-type-mean-in-c

Comment: It refers that the value type (here int?) is a nullable type.

Answer (score 551, accepted):

It means that the value type in question is a [nullable type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s(v=vs.140).aspx)

> Nullable types are instances of the System.Nullable struct. A
>   nullable type can represent the correct range of values for its
>   underlying value type, plus an additional null value. For example, a
>   `Nullable<Int32>`, pronounced "Nullable of Int32," can be assigned any
>   value from -2147483648 to 2147483647, or it can be assigned the null
>   value. A `Nullable<bool>` can be assigned the values true, false, or
>   null. The ability to assign null to numeric and Boolean types is
>   especially useful when you are dealing with databases and other data
>   types that contain elements that may not be assigned a value. For
>   example, a Boolean field in a database can store the values true or
>   false, or it may be undefined.
>
> ```
> class NullableExample
> {
>   static void Main()
>   {
>       int? num = null;
>
>       // Is the HasValue property true?
>       if (num.HasValue)
>       {
>           System.Console.WriteLine("num = " + num.Value);
>       }
>       else
>       {
>           System.Console.WriteLine("num = Null");
>       }
>
>       // y is set to zero
>       int y = num.GetValueOrDefault();
>
>       // num.Value throws an InvalidOperationException if num.HasValue is false
>       try
>       {
>           y = num.Value;
>       }
>       catch (System.InvalidOperationException e)
>       {
>           System.Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
>       }
>   }
> }
> ```

Comment: Used for struct. Don't think it is actually useful for classes.

Comment: @MonsieurDart - thats why the answer says "value type"

Comment: Why does C# have this when most primitives already have a nullable type (Ex: int/Integer, double/Double, etc.)?

Comment: @AntoineDahan - values types do not have nullable types as they are by definition non-nullable. I think you're thinking of Java where there is an `int` type and a corresponding `Integer` class, for example.

Comment: more recent (2015) documentation for nullable type [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s(v=vs.140).aspx)

Comment: Also note that [question mark can follow an object (instance of a type)](http://www.kunal-chowdhury.com/2014/12/csharp-6-null-conditional-operators.html#t6MtXHTTG6yPywQp.97) in c# 6 (VS 2015)

Comment: Found this to be very useful! I did have to implement it in mvc using ...(int? id = 0), so that I was able to call it with an empty parameter(). In my method, I had to code for both conditions. This saved me from having duplicate methods with overrides.

Comment: *null* cannot be assigned to value types and primitive types, C# 2.0 introduced the mechanism *nullable type* so that value/primitive types can be assigned null.  @ZimSystem, following question mark after reference **?.** type is very different operator called *null conditional operator*. It evaluates the expression to null if an instance is null (without throwing NullReferenceException). Consider old way *address = (emp.Address != null) ? emp.Address : null* => *address = emp?.Address*

Answer (score 150):

It is a shorthand for [`Nullable<int>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/nullable-types/index). `Nullable<T>` is used to allow a value type to be set to `null`. Value types usually [cannot be null](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/value-types#main-features-of-value-types).

Comment: The second sentence confuses me. What do you mean by "cannot"? On the compiler level or in the application context.

Comment: @problemofficer per definition, `value types` cannot be null. If you declare an int or a bool (which are value types) without specifically assigning a value, they would still have values (0 and false, respectively), ie. they would not be null. Unassigned `reference types`, such as object or MyClass, will, on the other hand, be null. You might want to read up on the difference between value types and reference types.

Answer (score 69):

In

```
x ? "yes" : "no"
```

the **?** declares an **if** sentence. Here: **x** represents the boolean condition; The part before the **:** is the **then** sentence and the part after is the **else** sentence.

In, for example,

```
int?
```

the **?** declares a nullable type, and means that the type before it may have a null value.

Comment: I disagree with the comment above from Gus.  The question shows that there is a possible confusion with the ternary expression.  This answer addresses this issue.

Comment: Where would you use this kind of null-comparing? Inside a return it seems to not be allowed. `return value ? value : "isNull";` tells me that `string value` isnt convertable into bool.

Comment: I must say this is a very convoluted answer, especially when compared to others on this question.. -1

Comment: The question states that it is NOT about the x ? "yes" : "no", but about when using question mark after a type declaration. This is a really bad answer in my opinion.

Answer (score 17):

it declares that the type is nullable and you can use this without giving any value.

Answer (score 7):

practical usage:

```
public string someFunctionThatMayBeCalledWithNullAndReturnsString(int? value)
{
  if (value == null)
  {
    return "bad value";
  }

  return someFunctionThatHandlesIntAndReturnsString(value);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

`int?` is shorthand for `Nullable<int>`. The two forms are interchangeable.

`Nullable<T>` is an operator that you can use with a value type `T` to make it accept `null`.

In case you don't know it: [value types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/value-types) are types that accepts values as `int`, `bool`, `char` etc...

They can't accept references to values: they would generate a compile-time error if you assign them a `null`, as opposed to [reference types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types), which can obviously accept it.

Why would you need that?
Because sometimes your value type variables could receive null references returned by something that didn't work very well, like a missing or undefined variable returned from a database.

I suggest you to read the [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/nullable-types/index) because it covers the subject quite well.

Comment: if the two forms are interchangeable, how come one gives a compile-time error and the other doesn't? Compare `public Item? item { get; set; };` with `public Nullable<Item> item { get; set; };` where Item is some trivial class.

Comment: @MattiasMartens `Item` has to be a value type (a struct) - classes are reference types. [A nullable reference type is something quite different](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references), unfortunately with identical syntax which causes some confusion.

Answer (score 6):

Means that the variable declared with (int?) is nullable

```cs
int i1=1; //ok
int i2=null; //not ok

int? i3=1; //ok
int? i4=null; //ok
```

Answer (score 3):

To add on to the other answers:

Starting in C# 8.0, `Nullable<>` and `?` are NOT always interchangeable. `Nullable<>` only works with **Value types**, whereas `?` works with **both Reference and Value types**.

These can be seen here in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references)

> "A nullable reference type is noted using the same syntax as nullable
> value types: a `?` is appended to the type of the variable."

And [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.nullable-1?view=net-6.0)

> `public struct Nullable<T> where T : struct`

Answer (score 1):

To add on to the answers above, here is a code sample

```
struct Test
{
    int something;
}
struct NullableTest
{
    int something;
}
class Example
{
    public void Demo()
    {
        Test t = new Test();
        t = null;

        NullableTest? t2 = new NullableTest();
        t2 = null;
    }
}
```

This would give a compilation error:

> Error 12  Cannot convert null to 'Test' because it is a non-nullable
>   value type

Notice that there is no compilation error for NullableTest. (note the ? in the declaration of t2)