# What does the question mark in "Decimal?" mean?

Tags: c#

I am following tutorials about MVC4 asp.net. The tutorials are using `Decimal` like this:

```
     public Decimal x{ set; get; }
     public Decimal? y{ set; get; }
```

what does it mean when using `?`  after `Decimal`

Comment: It means it can be null

Comment: It's actually a `Nullable<Decimal>`

Comment: thanks, didn't pay attention it was duplicated..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It means that the value type in question is a nullable type

see here

[What is the purpose of a question mark after a type (for example: int? myVariable)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2690866/c-sharp-using-the-question-mark-after-a-type-for-example-int-myvariable-what)

Comment: well you deserve the accepted answer, thx sir.