# Nullable int as action parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

in this Code

```
public ActionResult Index(int? id)
{
  return View();
}
```

What does the `int? id` do?

Can we write it in this format also?

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
  int id;
  return View();
}
```

Comment: I've changed title so it does not look like OP had not tried to search https://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+int+question+mark and read about nullable types like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2690866/what-is-the-purpose-of-a-question-mark-after-a-type-for-example-int-myvariabl

Answer (score 6):

It allows you to pass a parameter to the Action.

If you have a route specified like this:

```
"{controller}/{action}/{id}"
```

Then you will be able to call the URL `YourController/Index/1` and the `1` will be passed into your action.

The question-mark after the `int` means that it is a `Nullable<int>` aka it is an optional parameter. If it's not in the URL the id will be `null`

Your alternate syntax does not work.

Comment: what if i didn't put the int parameter? lets say Its Index(String somevalue)

Answer (score 4):

`Id` is a parameter of your Index action method. With the default route definitions, When a request comes for your Index action method ,the part of your url(URL segment) which has the value for your Id param will be mapped to the `Id` param of your Action method.

For example,  for the request `yourSiteName.com/yourControllerName/Index/350`, your Index action method will be executed and `350` will be available in the `Id` parameter and will be accessible inside your method.

`int?` means it is nullable int which means the value can be null.When you do not provide value for a nullable int parameter, It will be NULL.

In terms of MVC routing, this means that the action method can be accessed like `yourControllerName/Index` and `yourControllerName/Index/23` ,with the default route definition. Sometimes people use this to return a List/Index view for the request without the Id value and return a specific item for the request with the Id passed in.

So before accessing the value, you should check whether it is null or not. If it is not null, you may use the Value property to get the value stored inside the param.

```
public ActionResult Index(int? id)
{
  if(id!=null)
  {
   //request came with a value for id param. Let's read it.
    var idValue =id.Value;
   //do something with the IdValue which is an Int       
  }
  else
  {
    //request came without a value for id param
  }
  return View();
}
```

Comment: When you have a class with `Int` type property and you do not set the value of this property on your class object, you get the 0 when you access it later, which i guess is the default for this value type. I Should not have mixed it with the action method param context i guess.

Comment: what if i didn't put the int parameter? lets say Its Index(String somevalue)

Comment: Then inside your action method, you can use string.IsNullOrEmpty(somevalue) to check a value came in the the request. Since the param name is not id, url should be index?somevalue=abc