# C# events with nullable reference types enabled - how to declare?

Tags: c#, events

Before we had Nullable Reference Types (NRT) in C#, events and trigger methods would be declared like this:

```cs
public event EventHandler MyEvent;

private void TriggerEvent()
{
    this.MyEvent?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

Now, with NRTs enabled, should the event type be declared as `EventHandler` or `EventHandler?`:

```cs
public event EventHandler MyEvent;
// or
public event EventHandler? MyEvent;

private void TriggerEvent()
{
    this.MyEvent?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

I'd say `EventHandler?` but all the C# documentation I could find (still) says `EventHandler` (without `?`).

**Update:** Editing this question because someone (?) flagged this as duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2690866/what-is-the-purpose-of-a-question-mark-after-a-type-for-example-int-myvariabl) - which is clearly not a duplicate. I know what `?` means. That's not the question here.

Comment: I deleted my previous comment as it contained false information, turns out, Microsoft aimed to be done with null-annotating their core libraries once .NET 5 released and their progress was tracked in [this](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/2339) GitHub issue. So it seems like only the documentation is lacking, but yes, you should definitely use `EventHandler?`

Comment: Do you get a compiler warning or what is wrong with old version? You can set [#nullable disable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references) and use old syntax.

Comment: FYI there was a discussion on this point here; https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/discussions/3016 with the consensus being that it didn't have any runtime impact, so there wasn't much point in changing anything.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are correct; it should indeed be `EventHandler?` since unsubscribed events (the default) are backed by a `null` delegate instance (at least when using field-like-events, as per here). The documentation simply doesn't always accommodate nullable reference type signatures.