# Why does reference types need nullable?

Tags: c#, null, nullable

```
string? nullableString
```

Nullable value types are understandable why they are needed.
But why reference types need nullable?

Comment: Nope, they don't *need* nullable. It's an [optional feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references) you can activate for additional type safety.

Comment: They don't need it - related question asked a few hours ago - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69433546/what-does-question-mark-after-reference-type-parameter

Comment: If you are reading from a database you may need to use DBNull.Value

Comment: @jdweng What does that have to do with anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Nullable references types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references) were added to the language to decrease likelyhood of null reference exception via static code analysis by compiler:

> - Improved static flow analysis that determines if a variable may be null before dereferencing it.
> - Attributes that annotate APIs so that the flow analysis determines null-state.
> - Variable annotations that developers use to explicitly declare the intended null-state for a variable.

Nullable reference types is an opttional feature which can be enabled/disabled for example on file or project level.