# How can I resolve .NET Core with EF Core required field error?

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a .NET Core (6.0.1) API that was constructed using DB first method with EF Core (6.0.1). Whenever I try to POST to a specific entity, I am getting a "field is required" error for one of the navigation properties in the entity. I have several other entities structured in a similar way that seem to be working fine, but this one is causing me issues and I cannot figure it out. Any ideas?

From DBContext:

```
    modelBuilder.Entity<InsuranceCompanyStatus>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => e.InsCoStatusId);

            entity.ToTable("InsuranceCompanyStatus");

            entity.Property(e => e.InsCoStatusId).HasColumnName("InsCoStatusID");

            entity.Property(e => e.InsuranceCompanyId).HasColumnName("InsuranceCompanyID");

            entity.Property(e => e.State)
                .HasMaxLength(2)
                .IsUnicode(false)
                .IsFixedLength();

            entity.HasOne(d => d.InsuranceCompany)
                .WithMany(p => p.InsuranceCompanyStatuses)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.InsuranceCompanyId)
                .HasConstraintName("FK_InsuranceCompanyStatus_InsuranceCompanies");
        });
```

Scaffolded Model:

```
    public partial class InsuranceCompanyStatus
    {
      public int InsCoStatusId { get; set; }
      public Guid InsuranceCompanyId { get; set; }
      public string State { get; set; } = null!;
      public bool Admitted { get; set; }
      public bool? Approved { get; set; }

      public virtual InsuranceCompany InsuranceCompany { get; set; } = null!;
    }
```

JSON from Attempted POST Body:

```
    {
     "insuranceCompanyId": "caa3e956-a3be-4670-83e3-53a6ec47731e",
     "state": "AL",
     "admitted": true,
     "approved": true
    }
```

Error response status is 400:

```
    {
     "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
     "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
     "status": 400,
     "traceId": "00-cf1de6fe8e4fb67a04ff7d4c8b6a1c68-f426059123424d72-00",
     "errors": {
        "InsuranceCompany": [
        "The InsuranceCompany field is required."
     ]
    }
    }
```

Comment: It's good to see the classes and mappings and the posted content, but the actual running code that throws an exception should never be missing in a question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have to make nullable InsuranceCompanyId

```
public partial class InsuranceCompanyStatus
{
    public int InsCoStatusId { get; set; }
    
    ....
    public Guid? InsuranceCompanyId { get; set; }
    
    public virtual InsuranceCompany InsuranceCompany { get; set; }  // = null!; you don't need it , it is null by default
}
```

it usually works, but if it still not working you can add it explicitly in fluent appi

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<InsuranceCompanyStatus>(entity =>
 {
   .....  
   entity.Property(e => e.InsuranceCompanyId).IsOptional();
```

Answer (score 3):

I had this scenario going on:

- I had a NOT NULL foreign key in my table;
- C# 8.0 introduced [nullable reference types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-8#nullable-reference-types) - yes, a type designation for a variable stating that it's data type is a *reference that can be null* (I thought that was implicit but [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69433546/what-does-a-question-mark-after-a-reference-type-mean-in-c) there's some clarification on the case for them);
- EF 6 [started using it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-6.0/whatsnew).

When I tried to insert a new record, I received the "field is required" error on the FK navigation property. If I changed the FK to a nullable column in the DB and re-scaffolded the code, everything worked fine.

There's some rationale and "by design decisions" in the [related EFCore Github project issue](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/15520) but it was too much for me to digest it so I went for the easy way out.

This is the original EF generated code:

> ```
> namespace DAback.Models
> {
>     public partial class Patient
>     {
>         // ...
>         public int CurrentQueue { get; set; }  // FK to Queue table
>
>         public virtual Queue CurrentQueueNavigation { get; set; } = null!;
>     }
> ```

The "field is required" error was generated because the object provided to the insert method had no value on the **CurrentQueueNavigation** property (although **CurrentQueue** was populated).

I tried the recomendations here about declaring the get/set property as nullable, and setting the scaffolded property as not required during context initialization (**OnModelCreating**) but nothing. So I declared the navigation property type as a nullable reference type and all worked ok:

> ```
> namespace DAback.Models
> {
>     public partial class Patient
>     {
>         // ...
>         public int CurrentQueue { get; set; }  // FK to Queue table
>
>         // Using "Queue?" instead of "Queue" so EF now knows this
>         // object doesn't need to be present on deserialization
>         // i.e., it can be null
>         public virtual Queue? CurrentQueueNavigation { get; set; } = null!;
>     }
> ```