# Microsoft motivation to create nullable reference types

Tags: c#, nullable-reference-types

In C#-8 we have seen `nullable reference types`. I noob in C# and I don't know why it's neccessary?

Ok, I have methods:

```
#nullable enable
public void Method1(string? arg) { }
#nullable disable
```

```
public void Method2(string arg) { }
```

What are the **principial** differences between `Method1` and `Method2`?

Comment: Read my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69433657/4800344 - does that help?

Comment: Also [this blog post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/nullable-reference-types-in-csharp/) and [this one](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/embracing-nullable-reference-types/)

Comment: @canton Does it just help you write code more safely (escape NullReferenceException)?

Comment: Yes. But there's no "just" -- avoiding unexpected nulls is a huge benefit, particularly in larger codebases where it's harder to keep track of the edge cases where things can be null by yourself

Comment: A frequently asked question here is "why is my code throwing this nullreference exception". So preventing that is quite a big deal