# What is the use of the symbol "?" in the code "string?" in C#?

Tags: c#

I'm new to C#, I've seen some people write `string? SomeVar;` in YouTube. I just want to know what is the use of the `?` symbol.

I've tried to Google it but I didn't get anything I wanted.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nullable-value-types

Comment: @FranzGleichmann `string` is not a value type.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the purpose of a question mark after a value type (for example: int? myVariable)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2690866/what-is-the-purpose-of-a-question-mark-after-a-value-type-for-example-int-myv)   (that link is in the top then of a simple search result: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%23%5D+question+mark+)

Comment: Better duplicate link if there are any gold-badgers around https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69433546/what-does-a-question-mark-after-a-reference-type-mean-in-c

Answer (score 2):

C# 8 has introduced a new feature called [nullable reference types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references):

> In a nullable oblivious context, all reference types were nullable. Nullable reference types refers to a group of features enabled in a nullable aware context that minimize the likelihood that your code causes the runtime to throw `System.NullReferenceException`. Nullable reference types includes three features that help you avoid these exceptions, including the ability to explicitly mark a reference type as nullable:
>
> - Improved static flow analysis that determines if a variable may be null before dereferencing it.
> - Attributes that annotate APIs so that the flow analysis determines null-state.
> - Variable annotations that developers use to explicitly declare the intended null-state for a variable.

So `string?` denotes a nullable string which allows compiler to emit appropriate warnings when developer does not perform appropriate checks  to reduce NREs.

Note that there is another similar feature - [nullable value types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nullable-value-types) which is a bit different (which worth a separate discussion =).

Read more:

- [Reference types (C# reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types)
- [Value types (C# reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-types)
- [Null References: The Billion Dollar Mistake](https://www.infoq.com/presentations/Null-References-The-Billion-Dollar-Mistake-Tony-Hoare/)

Answer (score 0):

`?` means that the field\property can be null. `string?` is a nullable string,
`int?` is a nullable int and so on.

Comment: The `?` on a value type like int _"means that the field\property can be null"_.  The use of `?` on a reference type is much more nuanced.  Remember that `string someNullString = null;` is perfectly good code.