# What does a "?" mean in the definition of a class member?

Tags: c#

I'm familiar with the use of "?" as a checked access operator. However, I don't understand how it's used in class member definitions. For example, in this definition:

```
private Socket? newSocket;
```

What does the question mark indicate?

Comment: That property is nullable. So it can be either a Socket Instance or null.

Comment: Just a little historical context. Nullable types that you may read about in textbooks could be the C# 2 (2006) versions, back then if you saw it it was because programmers didn't understand it (only did something for int etc.). But since C#10 (2021) it now has meaning.

Comment: Possible duplicates : if `Socket` [is a reference type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69433546/10352740) and if [it's a value type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2690866/10352740)

Comment: It's just nullable property, you can pass Socket class instance or it may be a null value.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the type of the variable `Socket` (if it's a reference or a value type), but in general it means that the variable is nullable.

If it's a reference type (like a class, for example), and the nullable context is enabled, then it's just an "indication" for the compiler, as reference types can be null even if you indicate them as non nullable. You can find more info about this in the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references).

If it's a value type (like a struct), then this means that the variable can be null. If there was no question mark then it wouldn't be possible to assign null to it.