# how to down cast in c#

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Typecasting in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1339482/typecasting-in-c)

how do I down cast in c#?

Answer (score 11):

You just use the normal (cast) operator:

```
class HigherTypeInHierarchy {}
class LowerTypeInHierarchy : HigherTypeInHierarchy {}

var lowerTypeInHierarchy = new LowerTypeInHiearchy();

// OK downcast:
HigherTypeInHierarchy someObject = lowerTypeInHierarchy;
var okDowncast = (LowerTypeInHiearchy)someObject; // OK
```

Of course, for the cast to be valid, the object you try to cast must be of the type you cast to, or you will get a runtime Exception:

```
class AnotherLowerTypeInHierarchy : HigherTypeInHierarchy {}
var anotherLowerTypeInHierarchy = new AnotherLowerTypeInHiearchy();

// Failing downcast:
HigherTypeInHierarchy someObject = anotherLowerTypeInHierarchy;
var failedDowncast = (LowerTypeInHiearchy)someObject; // Exception!
```

If you just want to "try-cast" (i.e. are prepared to handle the situation where the type you attempt to downcast is not in fact of the designated type, use the *as*-cast instead:

```
var lowerTypeInHiearchyOrNULL = someObject as LowerTypeInHiearchy;
```

Downcasting is generally a bad idea, since it implies knowledge of the type outside the type system. Operations on higher levels in the hierarchy are supposed to work equally for all derived types (see [Liskov substitution principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)), yet by downcasting you state a contrary requirement that the type is in fact of a specific derived type).

Comment: where class LowerTypeInHiearchy { /* code * / } and                class HigherTypeInHierarchy : LowerTypeInHiearchy { /* code */ }

Comment: @ralf Yes, this should be pointed out - example edited accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

```
Class Animal {  }

Class Dog : Animal {  }

Dog dog = new Dog();
Animal animal = dog; //upcasting
Dog sameDog = (Dog)animal; //Downcasting
```

Answer (score 1):

http://igoro.com/archive/fun-with-c-generics-down-casting-to-a-generic-type/

Have a look at the URL above.

Also, think link that @Barry has posted would be my second choice for links because it is very simple example to follow.