# C Sharp Event Handler

Tags: c#, event-handling

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button source = (Button)sender;
    MessageBox.Show("The message inside the button is " + source.Text);
}
```

I am following a tutorial on C sharp's Event Handler , I was a Python user,

```
public static void Main()
{
    Message myMessage = new Message();
    myMessage.ShowMessage += new MessageHandler(myMessage.DisplayMessage);
}
```

I kind of know the basic syntax of creating new instances of a class now, but I don't get why there is a bracket for the Button in the first line.What are the differences between these two codes ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here (Button) is used to cast  object sender to button type  because you want the type in button. and in second example as you have mentioned its creating instance of Message class.

For more information go through this

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms173105.aspx

[Typecasting in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1339482/typecasting-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 4):

In c# every class is inherited from `object` class. as `Object` is a parent class it can be used to instantiate any child class. so here when we receive an `object` class instance we expect it to be a `Button` so we parse it into a `Button` object

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

here `sender` is specified as an object type variable.

```
Button source = (Button)sender;
```

Here that object variable `sender` is parsed into a `Button` object and save in a `Button` Type variable

Answer (score 1):

`sender` is an `object`. In order you get the `Text` property of the button, whose click handler is `button1_Click`, you have to cast the `sender` to an object of type `Button`, in order later get `source.Text`.

Actually, the `sender` is the control that the action is for. Because all the types in .NET inherit the base type `System.Object`, in order you get a specific property of the button, you have to cast the sender to an object of type `Button`.