# Why does chaining not work here, and I must set an intermediary variable?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am relatively new to C#. I have the following excerpt of a script:

```
public class Flipper : MonoBehavior {
  HingeJoint hinge;
  void start () {
    hinge = GetComponent<HingeJoint>();
    hinge.limits.min = 0;
  }
}
```

The line `hinge.limits.min = 0`; does not compile; I need to instead do it in two steps, with intermediary variable assignment like so:

```
JointLimits limits = hinge.limits;
limits.min = 0
```

why is this the case?

Comment: `HingeJoint` doesn't implement the `min` property. `JointLimits` does.

Comment: You are implicit casting the object from `HingeJoint` to `JointLimits`. Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1339482/typecasting-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two reasons for this:

**1**.`JointLimits`  is a struct.

**2**.`JointLimits` is declared as auto-property variable.

`HingeJoint.limits` is a type of `JointLimits` which is a `struct` and declared as auto-property (`{ get; set; }`) so you can't modify a variable(`min`) that is inside it directly. You have to make a copy of the `struct`, modify the variable inside it then assign the struct back to `HingeJoint`. *The use of `struct` and the auto property to declare the limits variable is why you can't do that*.

```
public JointLimits limits { get; set; }
```

The-same thing applies to `transform.position`. You can't modify its *x*, *y*, *z* variables directly because position is a type of `Vector3` which is a `struct` and it is also declared as auto-property:

```
public Vector3 position { get; set; }
```

You have to make a copy of it first, modify it then assign it back to `transform.position`.

Another unrelated problem in your code is the `Start` function. It is `Start` not `start`.

```
HingeJoint hinge;

void Start()
{
    hinge = GetComponent<HingeJoint>();

    //Make Limit copy
    JointLimits limits = hinge.limits;

    //Modify limit variable
    limits.min = 0;

    //Assign back to HingeJoint
    hinge.limits = limits;
}
```