# C#, Get class properties

Tags: c#, class, oop, mvvm, prism

I have the following class structure:

[class structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aNEoS.jpg)

The user can select to work with SystemA or SystemB.

The following code is from the class that creates the main object:

```
public class MainViewModel()
{
    var project = new Project();
    project.PropAList = new List<IInterfaceA>();
    project.PropAList.Add(new SystemB());    
}
```

My problem is that i want to get to SystemB properties (like 'Date') from another class (ViewModel) that gets the 'project' object. But in this class i can see only the base properties (and IInterfaceA) of the object and not the objects that was implemented from the interfaces ("IsOpen' and 'Date').
For example: I have a method that sets the Date in some view model but i can't activate it because that i don't know if the user initiates SystemA or SystemB.

So i can't write for example:

```
project.PropAList[0].Date = "1.1.2000";
```

Thanks

Comment: `(project.PropAList[0] as SystemB).Date = "1.1.2000";` Although if that item is **not** a `SystemB` it will throw an exception, so consider a null check before the `.Date` assignment.

Comment: I would suggest that you check for the type, with:
```if(project.PropAList[0].GetType() == typeof(SystemB)){
    (project.PropAList[0] as SystemB).Date = "1.1.2000";
}
else if (project.PropAList[0].GetType() == typeof(SystemA)){
    // do the other thing
}
```

Comment: Consider using `is` rather than `GetType` @HeadhunterXamd .

Comment: Thanks,
I tested the classes for in interface and now it works.

`(project.PropAList[0] as IInterfaceB).Date = "1.1.2000";`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Typecasting in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1339482/typecasting-in-c-sharp)