# Meaning of code lines in c# for scripting in CATIA?

Tags: c#, macros, catia

```
PartDocument prtDoc = (PartDocument)CATIA.ActiveDocument;
Part part1 = prtDoc.Part;
```

Can anyone explain what the above two lines of code will do?

Comment: I am new to MACROS. I record the macro in CATIA and try to edit in VisualStudio. So, I am trying to understand from basics. Can you tell me when to need typecast? For instance in the line below 
OriginElements originElements1 = (OriginElements)part1.OriginElements;
IT was saying that the cast is redundant.

Comment: Your question is pretty unclear. We don´t know what you already know about programming in general. E.g. do you know what a class is? What a property is? What a cast is? All those things are shown in your code, however we don´t know where **specifically** you´re struggling.

Comment: I am struggling when to typecast and when not to do while using macros

Comment: I don´t what what `ActiveDocument` is, but I suppose it´s not defined as `PartDocument` at compile-time. That´s why you need a cast.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1339482/typecasting-in-c-sharp

Comment: By the way: whoever "IT" is - maybe ReSharper ?? - when "IT" sais the cast is redundant you can surely omit it as it is meaningless.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are asking about type conversion. 
You should get to know the concepts of `implicit conversion`, `explicit conversion` and `strong typing`.
You can check which type is returned by given code, in your case `CATIA.ActiveDocument;` and with knowledge from above, you will know

> when to typecast and when not to do

You can learn more about C# typing from official documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/casting-and-type-conversions)